# Set ComboBox SelectedIndex

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a ComboBox which has objects of a **MyItem** class which has one string property and one integer property.

```
_myComboBoxItems = new List<MyItem>();
_myComboBoxItems.Add(new MyItem("stringId1",intId1));
_myComboBoxItems.Add(new MyItem("stringId2",intId2));
_myComboBoxItems.Add(new MyItem("stringId3",intId3));

MyCombo.ItemsSource = _myComboBoxItems;
```

I now want to set the **SelectedIndex** of **_myComboBoxItems** based on a **MyItem** object passed into my function.

```
void ChangeSelectedItem(MyItem item)
{
    MyCombo.SelectedIndex = find the index of the _myComboBoxItems that has an intId of e.g. item.intId
}
```

How can I do this? How do I search the items of _myComboBoxItems and get the item that has a value that matches the value I pass in.

Comment: `for(int i = 0; I < whatever.length; i++)if (collection[i].derp == true)muhCombo.SelectedIndex = i;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use some LINQ:

```
void ChangeSelectedItem(MyItem item)
{
    MyCombo.SelectedIndex = _myComboBoxItems.IndexOf(_myComboBoxItems.FirstOrDefault(x => x.intId == item.intId));
}
```

Note that you might as well set the `SelectedItem` property of the `ComboBox`:

```
void ChangeSelectedItem(MyItem item)
{
    MyCombo.SelectedItem = MyCombo.Items.OfType<MyItem>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.intId == item.intId);
}
```

Then you don't need to find the index in the `List<T>`.